# nodejs and mongodb adapter, quering using OR condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, adapter

i'm using nodejs with mongo adpater, i try to query a collection using OR condition in this way:

```
var itemFilter = [];

itemFilter.push({visible: true});

if (req.param('s')) {
    itemFilter.push({$or: [{name: req.param('s')}, {itemCode: req.param('s')}]});
}
GSDItem.find(itemFilter)
  .sort({'name': 1})
  .exec(function (err, responseItems) {
        items = responseItems;
        return callBack();
  });
```

find() return always an empty array. How i can do an OR condition in the right way?

Comment: Do you have an example of a document that should match the query but isn't? It's not clear if it's not working or if there's no matching documents.

Comment: I can't post the document, but i'm sure that i have data mathcing thid conditions, i can see it in mongo console